# Auto Left Click on Hold?

Tags: macros, mouse

I want my mouse to rapidly autoclick when I hold the left mouse button, how can I do this?
I have searched for hours, I didn't find anything!
Thanks in advance.

EDIT: P.S.: I want the rapid click to stop as soon as I release the left button.

Answer (score 0):

Can you be slightly more specific? Are you trying to write out the program of just finding an auto clicker application?

If you are looking for the application only, then there is alot available online. Just google. One such application could be: http://auto-clicker-by-shocker.soft32.com/

If you are trying to write a program, its pretty simple too, but you need to let me know what language you are using, if its OOP, I should be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I made an AutoHotKey script:

```
Suspend, On

~XButton2::Suspend, Toggle

~LButton::
    While GetKeyState("LButton", "P"){
        Click
        Sleep 50  ;  milliseconds
    }
return
```